# User/Role can Create table or view, but not select from it SQL Server 2008 - Ownership not passing to creator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, security, permissions, roles

I'm trying to create a role to give a few users permission to create and alter views, procedures and tables. 
I don't want these users to be able to select from/update/delete/alter etc. *any* table in the database, there are tables we want to keep control of - but they should have full permissions on any objects they create.

I've given the users permissions to create views etc. and that works fine, but they can't then select from views they then create. Is it possible to do this?

-- ADDED 25/july/2013

Example:
An example user Mike has specific permissions granted on a handful of tables. All Grant, no Deny.
No other database level permissions beyond "connect"
Plus is a member of public (not altered - no denys), plus 3 other roles we have set up

Role: Standard_Reader
Specific Select permissions on a number of tables. All Grant, no Deny.
No other database level permissions

Role: SensitiveDemographicsReader
Specific Select permissions on sensitive tables. All Grant, no Deny

Role: Analyst
No Specific securables
Database level permissions:
Create Function
Create Procedure
Create Table
Create View

This user can create a table or view, but once created, can't select from it.

Is it possible to set up SQL server so that whenever a user user creates a table or view they then have permissions to select from it (assuming they have permissions on underlying tables in view)

-- EDIT

After some investigation it has become apparent that for some reason in our database, ownership of objects is not acruing to their creators.

Found using this code

```
select so.name, su.name, so.crdate from sysobjects so join sysusers su on so.uid = su.uid
order by so.crdate
```

All owners, with a couple of exceptions are DBO.

I can't understand why ownership is not passing to the creators of objects. Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're using to deny them in the first place is overriding the default settings. Can you post more information on what permissions the users have?

Can't comment :(

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Ok so you'd expect these permissions on objects they'd created to apply normally? (I did!) Ok I'll dig out the details of other permissions and see what might be interfering. There are definitely no "denials" of permissions on our system - we just grant or not grant so hopefully it's not too tangled a web.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but lack privileges; have you taken a look at [MySQL table permissions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant-table-structure.html)? It's a rather good system.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm afraid I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 rather than MySQL

Comment: Would you be interested in using the `GRANT SELECT ON (table name) TO (user name)` command, for example?

Comment: On the basis of that, it's hard to deny you posess a rapier wit, but in your eagerness to wield it you've rather missed the point -  the aim here is that the user, having created the table, has access to it without intervention. Quite a few systems make it possible to set different security for objects automatically based on ownership - ownership being assigned to the creator on creation of the object. I wondered if that was possible in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you need to grant SELECT on the schema to user/group:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO User/Group;
```